# add clickable div into a background div

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am want to add a clickable text into my div, but the problem is when i put my div an position background (z-index:-1) the text is not clickable, and when i change (z-index:0) work fine but my div isn't in background, can any one help me thanks :)

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>background</title>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .background-i{
                position: absolute;
                z-index: -1;
                top:0px;
                left: 0px;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 1000px;
                background-color: red;
            }
            .test{
                float: right;
                text-align: right;
                text-decoration: underline;
                position: relative;
                width   : 100 ;
                height  : 30;
                margin-right: 10px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                cursor:pointer;
                background-color: red;
            }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.ff').click(function(){
                alert('heeloo');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>


    <body >
    <button class='ff'>lolokkk</button>
    <button clas='close'>lolo</button><br><br>


<div class="background-i">  
    <div class="test" style="border:1px solid">
        <span class="ff">Close X</span>
    </div>
</div>


    <button>lolo</button><br><br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you need to use z-index: -1? A div element can hold text and backgrounds at the same time, why using two different layers if you can use only one?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you wanting to add clickable text to the background div - if so why not just put the text inside the div?  I don't get what the -1 z-index is for, which div is meant to be behind and which div is meant to be on top

Comment: what i am trying to do is to create a div with a text, so when i click on text i trigger a alert for exemple, and when i click on div i trigger a outher event, but my div should place in background. like this http://gallery.smartadserver.com/background-web-ad-format